# How to get all accounts from near protocol blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, nearprotocol

I am currently working on a program within the Near Protocol to generate user-specific Near token ownership statistics. However, I'm not sure how to obtain a list of all user accounts. Is there an indexer or any other method to obtain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEAR recently launched a BigQuery Public Dataset and you could use this query to get a list of active accounts:

```sql
select account_id 
from `bigquery-public-data.crypto_near_mainnet_us.accounts` 
where is_active = true;
```

Here is the documentation that explains how to use the dataset https://docs.near.org/bos/queryapi/big-query